# Changing the width of a button in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the width of a button to match the width of the text box above it in jquery. I have tried to accomplish this by using the following line:

```
$("#myButton").css("width", $("#textbox").width());
```

In the code below:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EfAJ/2/)

JQuery:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$("#myButton").css("width", $("#textbox").width());
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"> Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="productTab">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" class="buttons" class="ui-widget">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="textbox" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button id="myButton">My Button
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I believe that since I am using tabs, the width of the text box is not immediately available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because the textbox is hidden (in the tab which is not being displayed) and therefore it's width cannot be calculated. The work around is to clone the element, append it, then get it's width and finally remove it from the DOM.

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
var $textboxClone = $('#textbox').clone().appendTo('#tabs');
$("#myButton").css("width", $textboxClone.width());
$textboxClone.remove();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4EfAJ/8/)

Note; the minor difference in widths here is due to padding and/or margin differences which I'll let you solve in CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Get the width before you use `.tabs`:

```
var width = $("#textbox").width();
$('#tabs').tabs();
$("#myButton").css("width", width);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4EfAJ/12/

Comment: This is a neater solution than mine, +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the width once you click on the tab containing the form. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4EfAJ/16/

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$("#productTab").on("click",function() {
    $("#myButton").css("width", $("#textbox").width());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
$("#myButton").css("width", $("#textbox").css("width"));
```

Comment: This is in effect no different to what the OP already has, which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width of the button once its tab is visible, not before:

```
 $('#tabs').tabs({
  activate: function(event, ui){
    if (ui.newTab.index() == 1){
        $("#myButton").css("width", $("#textbox").width() );
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$("#textbox")` is invisible at the time page loaded, so you can't retrieve it's `width`. Try to put these stuff on the first tab. or resize the `width` when the second is active

Answer (score 0):

try this
first:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" **style="width:300px"** />
```

then

```
$("#myButton").css({width:$("#textbox").width()+"px"});
```

Hope it leads to some solution

Comment: Are you advising the use of inline styles? Running very close to a -1 for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Be more flexible just assign the width to the button. Doesn't madder if he is visible or not.

```
#textbox {
  width: 250px
}
```

If you can solve a problem by css always choose this way before you start javascript.